# SP2013 Changing URL of web results in List View Threshold error

Tags: 2013, list-view-threshold

Similar to this question, however the answer seems to have not paid attention to the actual problem- [TechNet Forum](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/sharepoint/en-US/f42f4f5c-c22d-4fc6-a330-b4776ebfb57e/i-cant-change-the-url-to-my-sharepoint-child-page)

I am attempting to change the URL of one of my site's child webs through "Site Settings -> Title, Description, and Logo" - the option for changing the URL is on this page. When setting the new URL, then clicking OK, I receive an error page

> "The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold enforced by the administrator."

I know all about list view threshold. What does it have to do with changing my site's URL? Is there a list in the config database that stores the URLs- and maybe there are too many webs or something for it to perform this type of operation? Seems terrible.